# MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench 10 is really very very slow

Tags: java, mysql, configuration

I am using MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench 10 and it is paid version. It is been very slow since i started to use it.

I really dont know what are all the things that i need to do to increase the speed.

this is my `myeclipse.ini`

```
#utf8 (do not remove)
#utf8 (do not remove)
-startup
../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../Common/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.i18n.win32.win32.x86_64_3.2.0.v201103301700
-install
C:/MyEclipse/MyEclipse 10
-vm
C:/MyEclipse/Common/binary/com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_64_1.6.0.013/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-Dosgi.nls.warnings=ignore
```

kindly help me.

```
System details

RAM : 8 GB 
OS : Windows 7 64 bit

JDK : 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-27215.html for some tips. However, there have also been improvements with newer releases. Try installing the latest release (currently 2014) for better support. If you have a current license, it applies to all releases of MyEclipse.